# Cmd not displaying correctly

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am on Windows 10. Today, I checked the "Legacy Console" option in the cmd console and it's working fine. But after disabling it, the console displayed a blank black console. It seems that the font color is not displayed correctly, since when I ran "color 0f" in that console (while not seeing anything), everything came back.

The interesting thing was that the normal cmd worked normally, but the cmd I started by running "start" using the Run Program wasn't displaying correctly. What's the difference between the two?

I tried to set the font color of the incorrectly displayed cmd. However, whenever I click on "properties", the cmd just disappeared. I can only open the "default" windows but nothing I set there seems to work. Here are the "default" windows settings.

One thing I can certainly do is to set autorun in the Registry Editor, but I don't want it to affect the color in my Powershell so I am looking for some alternative solutions. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set the same settings with no effect, so I don't think that they are
the problem.

Is it possible that you changed anything in the "Colours" tab of Properties?
Below are my settings.

**Screen background**

[image]

**Screen text**

[image]

Comment: I tried setting it. But what I set in the "default" tab had no effect on the console.

Comment: "Default" is only the default values. Do it for Properties, or actually for both.

Comment: I was not able to click "properties". But somehow I can now. Finally fix that :). Thx anyway.